# Make android app that is run as the only app on the android device.

Tags: android

I want to make an android app that runs as the only app on the android device. If the unit is reset I want this app to start up and run.

The reason for this is we are going to be buying these special 7 inch wall mounted tablets which have android OS on them (here is a link to the device: http://www.geekland.co/7-Android-42-Panel-PC-Wall-or-Desk-Mounted-Tablet-with-RJ45-GK-Q896.htm). And we are going to be programming an app that does various things.

However, it is imperative that the app cannot be exited and that if the system restarts, that app is what runs. We don't want random people messing with the device. We want to restrict everything just to that app.

Of course, maybe with an admin password you would be able to exit the app.

Can this be done somehow within an android app? Or does this call for, I don't know, making some new android OS clone or something? (something I'm not sure of how to do).

Comment: you are going to need a custom ROM, no way around it

Comment: @tyczj Thank you for the advice. I will look into how to create a custom android ROM and how to install it.

Comment: Uninstall everything but your app. Set up a script in the init folder which launches your app

Comment: You could make a custom Launcher. That should give pretty full control over what a user can do.

Comment: I don't think he needs a custom rom, he an overwrite the back and home button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969541/override-back-button-in-android and also make a wake broadcast receiver that init the app when the device start https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: @cgomezmendez you cannot override the home button

Comment: oh sorry, you are right is not working any more since 4.0 @tyczj

Comment: @tyczj are custom roms hard to make? I mean if you know how to make android apps that is. (dumb question but just want your insight since you seem to know)

Comment: also there is this, but only 5.0 > over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android/24540023#24540023

Comment: @AcroR I have no idea what is involved in making a ROM

Comment: @AcroR Check this, they have a working code that do exactly what you want http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are few ways to do this.

1. Override buttons as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862319/1454173)
2. Write a home screen application as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862095/1454173)
3. Lock apps using apps [similar](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=applock&c=apps) to [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) some can even lock system apps and settings

Answer (score 0):

If the devices are running Lollipop or newer, you can do this with the [Task Locking API](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu). First you need to make your app (or some other app) the device owner and grant your app the lock task permission so that locking can be done without user confirmation. Then just add a receiver in your manifest for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent and lock the task when the app starts.

I wrote an [open source app](https://github.com/kjkrum/DeviceOwner) that acts as the device owner and simplifies granting lock task permission to your own apps.